# The Fundamental theorem of calculus of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The Fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC) of complex function.

Consider:

$$\int_{\gamma } f(z) \ dz \ ,$$

$\gamma$ is a smooth curve included in a domain $G$. Does $f(z)$ continuous on $G$, imply $f$ has a anti-derivative? (In this case, it holds true for a real-valued function).

If not, then for the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus for Line Integrals of a complex function: Suppose $G$ is an open subset of the plane with $p$ and $q$ (not necessarily distinct) points of $G$.

Suppose $\gamma$ is a smooth curve in $G$ from $p$ to $q$. Then for any function $F$ analytic on $G$:

$$\int_{\gamma}F^{'}(z)dz=F(q)-F(p) \ .$$

But how do I explain the following process?

$$
   \int_{\gamma}f(z) \ dz
   = \int^{b}_{a}f(z(t)) \ z^{'}(t) \ dt  ,   \\
   = \int^{b}_{a}dW(t) \\
   =W(b)-W(a)
$$

$f(z(t)) \ z^{'}(t)$ is continuous, according to FTC of a real-valued function. It has anti-derivative. It just uses "$f(z)$ is continuous on $G$". The analytic function $F(z)$ is not be needed.

Comment: The main complication is path-dependence.  If we've already fixed a path, this is no longer a problem.

Comment: What is the function $W$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The antiderivative that the asker thinks should exist by the usual FTC